# Core Graphics: Gaps between rounded paths when stroking

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, rounded-corners, quartz-2d

I am using Core Graphics to make a rounded-rectangular floating dialog on the iphone.  When applying strokes along concentric rounded-rectangular paths, gaps between the strokes invariably appear in the corners.  These same strokes sit side-by-side on straight segments.

The pertinent excerpt from the code (extraneous code removed):

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect borderRect = CGRectInset(rect, 1.0, 1.0);
    UIBezierPath *borderPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:borderRect cornerRadius:6.0];
    [...]
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, bevelStrokeColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextAddPath(context, borderPath.CGPath);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    [...]
    CGRect inlayRect = CGRectInset(rect, inlayPathInset, inlayPathInset);
    UIBezierPath *inlayPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:inlayRect cornerRadius:6.0];
    [...]
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, inlayStrokeColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextAddPath(context, inlayPath.CGPath);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    [...]
}
```

Here's an image:

[image]

I have tried different versions of the code I posted above.  I have created the path manually, used the UIBezierPath instance methods to both create and draw, and I have set the cornerRadius via the view's layer as well as a few other ideas in various combinations.  Some of them ameliorated the problems, but obviation was not forthcoming.

If I only was using a border I wouldn't mind, but I have a few concentric rounded-rectangles I will be implementing as well and this gap will be a problem.

Edit: Corrected a typo in code that occurred when transcribed.

Comment: Just talking a guess here because I don't see a problem with your code and can't tell from the picture but what value is the variable `cornerRadius` when instantiating `inlayPath`? Could it be that it is 6.0 like the border path? Because you need to keep in mind that the radius of the inner side of the borderPath ist smaller than the outside. Thus you inlayPaths corner radius needs to be less than 6.0. If it's equal or larger you'll have the effect you're witnessing.

Comment: Oops.  I forgot to edit that to 6.0.  I took that out of the other path initialization.  They are both at 6, but that is not right.  I am trying to derive the math behind it now.  I will share if I come up with something.

Answer (score 3):

If `lineWidth` is the same for all strokes, setting `innerCornerRadius` to `(outerCornerRadius - lineWidth)` appears to produce the desired effect; it is a special case.  If you don't believe the following, I encourage you to test it.  The real relationship governing this seems to be as follows:

l<sub>i</sub> = line width inner

l<sub>o</sub> = line width outer

r<sub>i</sub> = corner radius inner

r<sub>o</sub> = corner radius outer

l<sub>i</sub>/2 + r<sub>i</sub> = r<sub>o</sub> - l<sub>o</sub>/2

Therefore:
r<sub>i</sub> = r<sub>o</sub> - (l<sub>i</sub>/2 + l<sub>o</sub>/2)

If l<sub>i</sub> = l<sub>o</sub> = l then:  r<sub>i</sub> = r<sub>o</sub> - l

```
/*
 The following should be inserted into a UIView subclass that has a size of ~280, ~200.

 lineWidthInner/2 + radiusInner = radiusOuter - lineWidthOuter/2
 radiusInner = radiusOuter - (lineWidthOuter + lineWidthInner)/2

 That is to say that the inner corner radius is equal to the outer corner radius 
     minus the average of the lineWidth's.


 innerInsetMargin = outerInsetMargin + (lineWidthOuter + lineWidthInner)/2

 The amount a line must be inset (insetMargin) is the previous line's insetMargin + the 
     average of the previous and current lineWidth's.  In the case in which the 
     outermost line's outer edge touches the bound of rect, the insetMargin is equal 
     to the sum of all previous lineWidth's plus half of the current lineWidth.

 Shutting off anti-aliasing is required to prevent alpha-blending of the non-rectilinear 
     parts of the line with the background.  I am not sure how to gracefully sidestep this.
     Insights into this would be appreciated.
*/
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context,NO);

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)UIColor.greenColor.CGColor, 
                       (id)UIColor.lightGrayColor.CGColor, 
                       (id)UIColor.yellowColor.CGColor,
                       (id)UIColor.blueColor.CGColor,
                       (id)UIColor.redColor.CGColor, nil];

    //Change lineWidth, lineWidthIncrement, or currentCornerRadius as you see fit
    CGFloat lineWidthIncrement = 1.0;
    CGFloat lineWidth = 10.0;
    CGFloat currentCornerRadius = 100.0;
    CGFloat insetMargin = lineWidth/2;

    do {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, (CGColorRef)[colors objectAtIndex:(lcv % colors.count)]);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
        CGContextAddPath(context, [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectInset(rect, insetMargin, insetMargin) cornerRadius:currentCornerRadius].CGPath);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        lineWidth += lineWidthIncrement;
        currentCornerRadius -= 0.5 * (lineWidth + (lineWidth - lineWidthIncrement));//-0.5*(lwi+lwo)
        insetMargin += 0.5 * (lineWidth + (lineWidth - lineWidthIncrement));

    } while(currentCornerRadius>0);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case your second corner radius has to be subtracted with your inlaypathinset too. The inner radius has to be smaller, otherwise the circle segments are not exactly concentric.

If, next to concentric, you also want both rounded rectangles to touch, then the inset needs to be the average of both line widths.

Comment: I figured out the answer.  This is wrong.  The radius must certainly decrease, but the relationship is much more mathematically beautiful.  I will post mine in 3 hours when SO allows.

Comment: I am curious, because I am quite convinced of my answer :-)

Comment: You are on the right track.  If you can convince me that I am wrong I will happily concede the point.  My answer soon.

Comment: @RGuy8032 I'm really looking forward to your mathematically beautiful answer, where is it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I seem to have hit a snag after I did some testing last night.  I am reworking my thesis.  I will post as soon as I come up with something credible.